# MySql - Update certain fields of a table with values from certain fields of same table

Tags: mysql, arrays

table_product_name

```
product_id | product_language | product_name
1            en                 apple pad
1            fr                 (empty)
2            en                 apple pod
2            fr                 (empty)
3            en                 apple mac
3            fr                 (empty)
```

I would like to create an update query that copies for each product_id the product_name in from the "en" row, to the row with same product_id with "fr" in the (empty) product_name field.

Thanks

Comment: Is 'empty' BLANK ('') or NULL (I hope it's NULL)

Comment: the second, it is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update p1
set p1.product_name = p2.product_name
from table_product_name p1
inner join table_product_name p2 on p2.product_id = p1.product_id and p2.product_language = 'en'
where p1.product_language = 'fr'
```

Comment: who adds description?

Comment: @Parixit what do you mean?

Comment: is this valid even if i'm working on the same table? there actually aren't 2 tables, its one unique table.

Comment: Yes, it is the same table with 2 different aliases so they can be self-joined, see here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm

Answer (score 0):

maybe you don't really need an UPDATE...

```
SELECT x.product_id
     , x.product_language
     , COALESCE(y.product_name,x.product_name) product_name 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.product_id = x.product_id 
   AND y.product_language = 'en';
```